# abp.io Problem add new record using CreateModalModel

Tags: abp

i am new to ABP.IO . while following the tutorial on abp.io to add book object i am getting this error DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Volo.Abp.Autofac.AbpAutofacConstructorFinder' on type 'hpDeskv2.Web.Pages.Products.CreateModalModel' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'hpDeskv2.Products.IProductsAppService productAppService' of constructor 'Void .ctor(hpDeskv2.Products.IProductsAppService)'. I could not get the modal to popup for inserting data.
Hope somebody would kind enough to help me
Thanks

Comment: Can you check, did your `IProductsAppService` derived from `IApplicationService`? Also, can you check the same for `ProductsAppService`? (it should be derived from both `ApplicationService` and `IProductsAppService`)

Comment: well as i am following the example from abp.io , my ProductsAppService is like this         public class ProductAppServices : CrudAppService<Product, ProductDto, Guid, PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto, CreateUpdateProductDto> ,IProductsAppService  while my    public interface IProductsAppService : ICrudAppService<ProductDto, Guid, PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto, CreateUpdateProductDto>

Comment: Can you share where you injected the `IProductsAppService`?

Comment: Injected in 2 class 1)ProductAppServices
   [Authorize(hpDeskv2Permissions.Products.Default)]
    public class ProductAppServices : CrudAppService<Product, ProductDto, Guid, PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto, CreateUpdateProductDto> ,IProductsAppService  
2)CreateModalModel
 public class CreateModalModel : ProductPageModel  {
       [BindProperty]
        public CreateProductViewModel Product { get; set; }
        private readonly IProductsAppService  _productAppService;
        public CreateModalModel(IProductsAppService prodAppService)
        { _productAppService = prodAppService; } }

Comment: just solve it , thanks for hint given to me . the problem is in the naming convation between ProductAppServices  and IProductsAppService and i change the IProductsAppService to IProductsAppServices..but still i could not understand how abp translate this.